# Set custom bashrc or PS1 variable

Tags: shell, bash, termux

I'm using, at the terminal on my android device, an simple approach to show the path to my location (`export PS1="(\w)$ "`). However, the `\w` seems to not be working in emacs shell emulator running inside termux. That is not really a problem, because I know where I am any time I run shell inside emacs. Is there some way to change default bashrc running by emacs, or just set `PS1` variable to be `"$ "` only for emacs?

Comment: Just as idea: Have you tried uppercase "W" (works for me)?

Comment: No, its still the same problem, I can see the string as I typed in to `PS1` not it's execution.

Comment: Oh, I missed the *shell*-part. "works for me" only in term (stupid me- sorry it's late here ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `INSIDE_EMACS` environment variable. If you genuinely want to restrict it to `M-x shell` usage, then you might do something like:

```sh
case $INSIDE_EMACS in
    *comint*) PS1="$ ";;
esac
```

I'd recommend figuring out which part of your system is responsible for it not working as expected, though.

Also: Your question was not quite a duplicate of [Startup script for term-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30669), but you should read that as well.