# Shell-mode execute script every time a shell is invoked

Tags: shell, shell-mode, wsl

I have changed the emacs-shell mode shell to WSL ubuntu but however, the prompt is not very user-readable. For this reason I would like to execute a script that changes it so that its more readable using:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$'
```

every time I enter `M-x shell`
At the same time, I would like to keep my prompt as is outside of emacs as it has color coding etc enabled so I want the change to only affect emacs hence my question. Is it possible?

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of either https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/38775/454 or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30669/454 but it's worth cross-referencing them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to execute a script [...] every time I enter `M-x shell`

This is supported as standard.

> Emacs sends the new shell the contents of the file
>   `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` as input, if it exists, where SHELLNAME is the name
>   of the file that the shell was loaded from.  For example, if you use
>   bash, the file sent to it is `~/.emacs_bash`.  If this file is not
>   found, Emacs tries with `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh`.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Interactive Shell`

---

I agree with @stsquad that testing `[ "$TERM" = "dumb" ]` makes good sense (as your use-case applies to *any* dumb terminal, not just in Emacs); but if you particularly wanted an Emacs-specific prompt, you can also do that within your normal shell config code:

When you are setting your normal fancy prompt you can test the environment variable `INSIDE_EMACS`.  For `M-x shell` the value will be along the lines of `26.1,comint` and the `comint` part tells you that you're in a dumb terminal and should set a simpler prompt.

```sh
# Set simpler prompt for M-x shell inside Emacs.
if [ "${INSIDE_EMACS%,comint}" != "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
  PS1='\u@\h:\w\$'
fi
```

Note that other values of `INSIDE_EMACS` are possible in other circumstances.  In `M-x term` (which isn't dumb) I see `26.1,term:0.96`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the *TERM* environment variable in your bashrc file. For M-x shell it will be "dumb" as opposed to anything else. For `ansi-term` the *TERM* environment variable is set to "eterm-color".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that I am unable to have Term run the wsl shell even though strangely I can do it for the shell command by changing explicit-shell variable. If you have managed to do it please advise.

Comment: @TeereraiMarange, this answer is not about any particular terminal emulator (I assume "Term" is a terminal emulator).   The `TERM` environment variable will be available in your shell no matter which terminal you are using.  e.g. `echo $TERM` from your shell prompt.  You would test it in your shell init code, at the point where you are currently setting your fancy prompt.